# How to show hidden text on hover using CSS

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I would like to show text when the mouse hovers over a button or `<a>` tag.

For example, I have this button with some text:

[image: Original button]

I have managed to make it larger when the mouse hovers over the button:

[image: Larger button on hover]

What I would like to do instead is keep the text and image on top and display some text beneath the button. Can anyone suggest how I might do this?

Comment: Post you code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if thats what you are looking for since you didn't include your code...

```css
div {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

a:hover+div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a><img src='http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/planetside2/images/4/4d/Scythe_Side_View_Icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20130426065845'></a>
<div>Display Whatever</div>
```

Comment: Thanks :) that is exactly what i needed :)

Comment: @DestHappy you can accept the answer in that case :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add hover state to parent element and styles to child

   `.parent .child {display: none}
   .parent:hover .child {display: block}`
2. Remember to put text you want to show in front of picture (posistion: absolute or/and z-index manipulation)